Why Ollama output is so different than online resources for the same model?
While testing the same model online (e.g. https://arena.lmsys.org/) and locally through Ollama, I am getting very different results.
Example for Gemma2:
Example of input:

You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:

Use modern C++20
Use the auto func(...) -> ret syntax, even for auto main()->int
Always open curly braces on new line: DONT auto main()->int{\n... (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: auto main() ->int \n{\n... instead (with new line between int and '{').
Comment your code.
No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code.


The output on lmsys is (quite consistently) similar to:
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The result on ollama is changing significantly between attempts, but it fails consistently:
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}

**Explanation:**

This program is written in C++20 and demonstrates the following:
... LONG TEXT HERE

Other models
Gemma2:27b is only one example, but I tried with ollama mixtral vs lmsys mixtral-8x22b-instruct-v0.1, ollama llama3 vs lmsys llama-3-8b-instruct, etc...
Hypothesis
My attempts to understand the difference:
Hypothesis 1: Temperature is set differently. I tried to change on lmsys the temperature with consistent results, and I also created a copy locally of gemma2:27b to set temperature to 0.0 but the results are worse.
Hypothesis 2: lmsys model is called 'gemma-2-27b-it' and is not exactly the same model. I could not find more information in this direction.
Hypothesis 3: quantization to 4bits reduce significantly the quality of the result.
Why results are different between Ollama gemma2:27b and lmsys gemma-2-27b?


Hypothesis 2: lmsys model is called 'gemma-2-27b-it' is not exactly the same model. I could not find more information in this direction.

In gemma-2-27b-it, it="instruction-tuned", so it'll outperform gemma-2-27b. See:

https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-2-27b
https://huggingface.co/google/gemma-2-27b-it


Hypothesis 3: quantization to 4bits reduce significantly the quality of the result.

Yes this too.

You can run code yourself to compare gemma-2-27b and gemma-2-27b-it, with and without 4-bit quantization:
Reqs:
pip install accelerate transformers torch bitsandbytes huggingface_hub
huggingface-cli login --token $HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN

where $HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN can be found on https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens, and go to google/gemma-2-27b to accept the access agreement.
Code:
input_text="""You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:
1) Use modern C++20 
2) Use the `auto func(...) -> ret` syntax, even for `auto main()->int`
3) Always open curly braces on new line: DONT `auto main()->int{\n...` (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: `auto main() ->int \n{\n...` instead (with new line between int and '{').
4) Comment your code.
5) No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code."""

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/gemma-2-27b")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "google/gemma-2-27b",
    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_length=1000)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/gemma-2-27b-it")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "google/gemma-2-27b-it",
    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_length=1000)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/gemma-2-27b")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "google/gemma-2-27b",
    device_map="auto",
    load_in_4bit=True
)
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_length=1000)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/gemma-2-27b-it")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "google/gemma-2-27b-it",
    device_map="auto",
    load_in_4bit=True
)
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(**input_ids, max_length=1000)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))

Output:
<bos>You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:
1) Use modern C++20 
2) Use the `auto func(...) -> ret` syntax, even for `auto main()->int`
3) Always open curly braces on new line: DONT `auto main()->int{
...` (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: `auto main() ->int 
{
...` instead (with new line between int and '{').
4) Comment your code.
5) No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code.
6) Use the `std::cout` and `std::endl` to print the result.
7) Use the `std::cin` to read the input.
8) Use the `std::string` to store the input.
9) Use the `std::vector` to store the output.
10) Use the `std::sort` to sort the output.
11) Use the `std::unique` to remove duplicates from the output.
12) Use the `std::copy` to copy the output to the `std::cout`.
13) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
14) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
15) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
16) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
17) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
18) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
19) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
20) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
21) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
22) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
23) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
24) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
25) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
26) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
27) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
28) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
29) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
30) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
31) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
32) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
33) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
34) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
35) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
36) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
37) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
38) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
39) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
40) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
41) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
42) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
43) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
44) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
45) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
46) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
47) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
48) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
49) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
50) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
51) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
52) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
53) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
54) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
55) Use the `std::endl` to print a new line.
56) Use the `std::cout` to print the output.
57) Use the `std::endl` to
<bos>You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:
1) Use modern C++20 
2) Use the `auto func(...) -> ret` syntax, even for `auto main()->int`
3) Always open curly braces on new line: DONT `auto main()->int{
...` (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: `auto main() ->int 
{
...` instead (with new line between int and '{').
4) Comment your code.
5) No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```<end_of_turn><eos>
<bos>You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:
1) Use modern C++20 
2) Use the `auto func(...) -> ret` syntax, even for `auto main()->int`
3) Always open curly braces on new line: DONT `auto main()->int{
...` (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: `auto main() ->int 
{
...` instead (with new line between int and '{').
4) Comment your code.
5) No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code.The first<pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad>
<bos>You are a software engineer experienced in C++:
Write a trivial C++ program that follow this code-style:
1) Use modern C++20 
2) Use the `auto func(...) -> ret` syntax, even for `auto main()->int`
3) Always open curly braces on new line: DONT `auto main()->int{
...` (with no new line between int and '{');  but DO: `auto main() ->int 
{
...` instead (with new line between int and '{').
4) Comment your code.
5) No explanation, no introduction, keep verbosity to the minimum, only code.<pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad><pad>

Observations:

gemma-2-27b-it  outperforms gemma-2-27
load_in_4bit=True messed up models too much, next step is looking at 4-bit models on HF directly.

Tested with Python 3.11.9 on Ubuntu and:
accelerate==0.32.0
bitsandbytes==0.43.1
huggingface-hub==0.23.4
torch==2.3.1
transformers==4.42.3

